# How can display Picker item of firebase realtime using xamarain forms and add to firebase when select item

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, timepicker, picker

I want to display a picker items from firebase how can do this ?

```
<Picker x:Name="AppointmentPatientName" Title="Patient Name" >
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Ahmad</x:String>
                <x:String>Ali</x:String>
                <x:String>Omar</x:String>
                <x:String>Alma</x:String>
                <x:String>Aya</x:String>
                <x:String>Ammar</x:String>
                <x:String>Noor</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>
```

Comment: query Firebase and put the results into an `IEnumerable`.  Then use that as the Pickers ItemsSource

Comment: @Jason can you give me more details?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what problem you're having?  Do you know how to write the FB query?  Do you know how to assign an ItemsSource for the Picker?  Both of these things are well documented.  Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you want to display Picker item of firebase realtime using xamarin forms, get the items from firebase first and then binding the items to the picker.

   Model:

   ```
   public class Person
   {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Get, add, delete items for firebase realtime database:

   ```
   public class FirebaseHelper
    {
    FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://fir-xxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");// the link you could get from your own firebase database. https://console.firebase.google.com/

    public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
    {

        return (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
          {
              Name = item.Object.Name,
              PersonId = item.Object.PersonId
          }).ToList();
    }

    public async Task AddPerson(int personId, string name)
    {

        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .PostAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name });
    }

    public async Task<Person> GetPerson(int personId)
    {
        var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>();
        return allPersons.Where(a => a.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public async Task UpdatePerson(int personId, string name)
    {
        var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();

        await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
          .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name });
    }

    public async Task DeletePerson(int personId)
    {
        var toDeletePerson = (await firebase
          .Child("Persons")
          .OnceAsync<Person>()).Where(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId).FirstOrDefault();
        await firebase.Child("Persons").Child(toDeletePerson.Key).DeleteAsync();

    }
   }
   ```

   Binding for the Picker:

   ```
      <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" >

                </Picker>
   ```
2. When you want to add item to firebase when select item, get the selected item first and then add it.

   Use the  `SelectedIndexChanged` event to get the selected item. And then call the Add method of the `FirebaseHelper`.

   ```
   void OnPickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    var picker = (Picker)sender;
    int selectedIndex = picker.SelectedIndex;

    if (selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        selectedItem = (string)picker.ItemsSource[selectedIndex];
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: selected item == Name ??  this is error ,,can solve depending on the class person ??

Comment: What does the `selected item == Name ??` mean? Could you give me more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
         MainPage.xaml 



            <Entry x:Name="TxtName" 
                   Placeholder="Name (Required)"/>
            
            <DatePicker x:Name="date"/>
            <Picker Title="Select a state"
                    x:Name="state"
                    TitleColor="Red">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>kerala</x:String>
                    <x:String>Pujab</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
            <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="BtnAdd" WidthRequest="200" Text="Add" Clicked="BtnAdd_Clicked"/>
                <Button x:Name="BtnDelete" WidthRequest="200" Text="Delete" Clicked="BtnDelete_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="BtnUpdate" WidthRequest="200" Text="Update" Clicked="BtnUpdate_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>

            <ListView x:Name="LstPersons" ItemSelected="LstPersons_OnItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage   
{         
    readonly FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        await FetchAllPersons();
    }

    private async void BtnAdd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsFormValid())
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "All are required fields", "OK");
            return;
        }

        Person person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(TxtName.Text);

        if (person != null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "A person with that name already exist", "OK");
            return;
        }

        await firebaseHelper.AddPerson(TxtName.Text,date.Date, (string)state.SelectedItem);

        TxtName.Text = string.Empty;           
        date.Date = DateTime.Now;
        state.SelectedItem = string.Empty;
       
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Added Successfully", "OK");

        await FetchAllPersons();
    }

    private async void BtnUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedPerson == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "A person must be selected to proceed", "OK");
            return;
        }
        
        if (!IsFormValid())
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "All are required fields", "OK");
            return;
        }

        Person person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(TxtName.Text);

        if (person != null && person.PersonId != SelectedPerson.PersonId)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "A person with that name already exist", "OK");
            return;
        }

        await firebaseHelper.UpdatePerson(SelectedPerson.PersonId, TxtName.Text, date.Date, (string)state.SelectedItem);

        TxtName.Text = string.Empty;           
        date.Date = DateTime.Now;
        state.SelectedItem = string.Empty;
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Updated Successfully", "OK");

        await FetchAllPersons();
    }

    private async void BtnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedPerson == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "A person must be selected to proceed", "OK");
            return;
        }

        await firebaseHelper.DeletePerson(SelectedPerson.PersonId);

        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Person Deleted Successfully", "OK");

        await FetchAllPersons();
    }

    private async void LstPersons_OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var person = await firebaseHelper.GetPerson(SelectedPerson.PersonId);

        TxtName.Text = person.Name;           
        date.Date = person.Date;
        state.SelectedItem = person.State;
    }

    private async Task FetchAllPersons()
    {
        var allPersons = await firebaseHelper.GetAllPersons();

        LstPersons.ItemsSource = allPersons;
    }

    private Person SelectedPerson => (Person)LstPersons.SelectedItem;

    private bool IsFormValid() => IsNameValid();

    private bool IsNameValid() => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtName.Text);
                  
}
```

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
   
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

FirebaseHelper.cs

```
public class FirebaseHelper

{
    
private readonly string ChildName = "Persons";

    readonly FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://XXXXXXyour__db_urlXXXXX/");

    public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
    {
        return (await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
            {
                PersonId = item.Object.PersonId,
                Name = item.Object.Name,                    
                Date = item.Object.Date,
                State = item.Object.State
            }).ToList();
    }

    public async Task AddPerson(string name,DateTime date, string state)
    {
        await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .PostAsync(new Person() { PersonId = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = name, Date = date,State=state });
    }

    public async Task<Person> GetPerson(Guid personId)
    {
        var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
        await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .OnceAsync<Person>();
        return allPersons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.PersonId == personId);
    }

    public async Task<Person> GetPerson(string name)
    {
        var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
        await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .OnceAsync<Person>();
        return allPersons.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name== name);
    }

    public async Task UpdatePerson(Guid personId, string name,DateTime date, string state)
    {
        var toUpdatePerson = (await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .OnceAsync<Person>()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId);

        await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .Child(toUpdatePerson.Key)
            .PutAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name,Date = date, State = state });
    }

    public async Task DeletePerson(Guid personId)
    {
        var toDeletePerson = (await firebase
            .Child(ChildName)
            .OnceAsync<Person>()).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Object.PersonId == personId);
        await firebase.Child(ChildName).Child(toDeletePerson.Key).DeleteAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ahed Hamad hi in the above answer am just created an entry for name, then date picker and picker for state selection. You can add FirebaseDb.net nuget package.

Comment: Try adding comments on what your code is doing inside the answer itself. It would better contribute to SO community and help others understand your answer.

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak In my answer am added an entry, date picker and a picker for state selection. In picker, values are added directly. like       <Picker.Items><x:String>kerala</x:String> <x:String>Punjab</x:String></Picker.Items>. These picker values have connected to real time firebase db. am also done CRUD operations with these values.

Comment: @Ahed Hamad I don't know this is what you exactly want. am also new to xamarin and stack overflow. You can have a look in to my answer. if it is not you means , Please neglect it. I just share some of my knowledge here. Thank you.